# Filtering an underscore.js max method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to get the max value of only two teams, there are several teams, but In my app I am trying to return the max value for the teams that are playing. They are set in a data attribute that I can access via jQuery. Below is my max variable.

```
var max = this.collection.max(function(player){
    return player.get('points');
});
```

I tried using the `where` function after `this.collection` and after `player` just to test it, and obviously it isn't valid, I feel like the answer is right in front of me, I've been through the docs, but I am not good enough with backbone.js yet to realize what I need to do here.

So what I am asking is how can I filter this max function to be limited to only two teams.

```
Lakers
Heat
Kings
```

The teams that are playing are `Lakers` and `Heat` set in the data-attribute, in the example below I am using a static string for the teams, I will substitute them for variables later, but I am more focused on the syntax. I am not sure how to do this, just some bad examples below.

```
//Bad example #1
var max = this.collection.where({teams: 'Lakers', teams: 'Heat'}).max(function(player) {
    return player.get('points');
})

//Bad example #2
if(this.collection.where({teams: 'Lakers'}) || this.collection.where({teams: 'Heat'})) 
    {
        var max = this.collection.max(function(player){
            return player.get('points');
        });             
    }
```

I don't think the examples above are valid or technically make sense to the browser, but hopefully they help you understand what I am going for?

Thanks, ask questions if you need to, this should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming teams is the property of player then try

```
var max = this.collection.max(function (player) {
    return player.get('teams') == 'Lakers' || player.get('teams') == 'Heat' ? player.get('points') : 0;
});
```

Comment: Oh nice, let me try it brb.

Comment: I see `teams` as an attribute on the model, but when I console.log `player.teams == 'Lakers'` I get false?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry can you add `console.log(player.teams, player.teams == 'Lakers')`

Comment: Yeah I can, I tried this syntax `return player.get('teams') == 'Lakers' || player.get('teams') == 'Heat' ? player.get('points') : 0;` and it worked, what do you think about that?

Comment: For some reason that console.log you asked me to do was undefined false. I don't think I can access `teams` like that. I need to use `.get('teams')`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry looks like it is a backbone model... might be because of that... haven't worked on backbone

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry yes I also think so.... because it is a backbone collection object

Comment: Okay cool it's working now, your logic was on point though and helped tremendously, edit the op and Ill award you :)